# How to prevent server side operations when Javascript Validation returns false?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to apply some client side validations using Javascript which is working fine,
But even when validation returns false the form goes to server side methods ex. `btnSubmit_Click()`
It may be happening because I'm calling the JavaScript function on `btnSubmit` like below:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="Javascript:validate()"/>`

I wants to check whether every Textbox values are valid or not, Then if all are valid then perform server side call i.e `btnSubmit_Click()` event else remain on same form until all values of TextBoxes are valid.

How to achieve this on single button?

Below is complete `JavaScript` function and `aspx` code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var summary = "";
            summary += isvalidFirstname();
            summary += isvalidEmail();
            summary += isvalidphoneno();
            if (summary != "") {
                alert(summary);
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        }
        function isvalidphoneno() {

            var uid;
            var temp = document.getElementById("<%=txtPhone.ClientID %>");
            uid = temp.value;
            var re;
            re = /^[0-9]d(10)/;
            var digits = /\d(10)/;
            if (uid == "") {
                return ("Please enter phoneno" + "\n");
            }
            else if (re.test(uid)) {
                return "";
            }

            else {
                return ("Phoneno should be digits only" + "\n");
            }
        }
        function isvalidFirstname() {
            var uid;
            var temp = document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID %>");
            uid = temp.value;
            var re = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/
            if (uid == "") {
                return ("Please enter firstname" + "\n");
            }
            else if (re.test(uid)) {
                return "";

            }
            else {
                return ("FirstName accepts Characters and spaces only" + "\n");
            }
        }
        function isvalidEmail() {
            var uid;
            var temp = document.getElementById("<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>");
            uid = temp.value;
            var re = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;
            if (uid == "") {
                return ("Please Enter Email" + "\n");
            }
            else if (re.test(uid)) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                return ("Email should be in the form ex:abc@xyz.com" + "\n");
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Employee Registration Form</legend>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Phone Number: </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Email Id: </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Address: </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="Javascript:validate()"/></td>
    </tr>  
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must return the value of the `validate` function in `OnClientClick`:

```
OnClientClick="return validate();"
```